# Matlab syntax error on [~, ...]

Tags: matlab, syntax-error

I have a working MATLAB code, which works fine on another machine, but when I run it on my own computer it detects the foloowing syntax error:

```
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.
```

This is my code:

```
    [~,x] = min(A);
```

Comment: I am using Matlab 7.8.0 R2009a 32bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of MATLAB are you using?

The `~` syntax for discarding unwanted return values was only introduced in R2009b.

EDIT: Had 2008a.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. but  
I am using Matlab 7.8.0 R2009a 32bit

Comment: I mis-spoke; [that syntax was only introduced in R2009b.](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/01/11/about-the-unused-argument-syntax-in-r2009b/). So this is indeed the problem. ;)

Answer (score 5):

You have an older version of MATLAB that doesn't recognize the "~" syntax.  Change the ~ to "junk" or some other variable name to remind yourself you don't care about the result and the code should run fine.

Or update your MATLAB to the latest version.